# CodeIgniter Nested Query

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, nested

I have a piece of code for getting conferences from database, where a specific subscriber is not subscribed.

I have two tables:

- `conferences` - which holds all conferences
- `read` -  which holds subscriber with conferences

Here is the code, but I get MySQL 1064 error.

```
function getPossibleConferencesOfSubscriber($sub_id)
{   
    $a = "SELECT * FROM conference C where C.ISSN not in (SELECT ISSN FROM read where sub_id=$sub_id)";                                                                     
    $query = $this->db->query($a);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Did you test via a "simple" MySQL interface (command line or phpmyadmin-style tool)?

Comment: I checked from PhpMyadmin but I got the same error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. I guess "read" is something like a command, so MySQL confuses the table name read and command read. I hope this helps someone, saves his 1 hour.